# How can I call a function before redirecting to the next URL in web2py?

Tags: python, html, crud, web2py

I've defined the form as follows:

```
form = crud.update(db.table, table_id, next=URL('nextpage'))
crud.settings.update_onaccept = myfunction()
```

I need to call myfunction() again after the form is submitted, but before the nextpage is loaded. 
Is there a crud setting that I can set that will call a function after the form has been submitted?

Comment: It looks weird that you're calling the function here.  I think it should be something like:  `sl = StorageList(); crud.settings.update_onaccept = sl; sl.append(myfunction)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why I need to use StorageList? @mgilson

Comment: I don't know either -- Just everything I found in the internet seemed to be using `StorageList`.  You could try it without calling the function:  `crud.settings.update_onaccept = myfunction`

Comment: No need to create an empty `StorageList`, as `crud.settings.update_onaccept` is initialized as an empty `StorageList`. In fact, it can simply be a regular Python dictionary (with table names as keys), list, or tuple, or just a single function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do:

```
crud.settings.update_onaccept = myfunction()
```

as you are calling `myfunction` right there, when you really just want to register it as a callback to be used later. Instead, use:

```
crud.settings.update_onaccept.tablename.append(myfunction)
```

Now, after the update has been accepted and applied, `myfunction` will be called, and the Crud `Form` object will be passed to it.

Note, if there is only one callback, you can also just do:

```
crud.settings.update_onaccept.tablename = myfunction
```

as there is no need to append to an existing list of callbacks.

Finally, if you want to use the same callback for all database tables (or are only using `Crud` for a single table), you can just do:

```
crud.settings.update_onaccept = myfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! However I now need to pass a parameter with myfunction(). Is this a problem? @Anthony

Comment: Not clear exactly what you want to do. Maybe open a new question and provide more details.